# elasticsearch index mapping

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I need to create and update index mapping using jest and transport client , but when i try with this tutorial https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-admin-indices.html#java-admin-indices-create-index-settings
i have this problem:

> Multiple markers at this line
>   - Syntax error on token ")", delete this token
>   - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after

This is my code:

```
Client client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));

        IndicesAdminClient indicesAdminClient = client.admin().indices();

        indicesAdminClient.prepareCreate("calls")
      .setSettings(Settings.builder()             
              .put("index.number_of_shards", 10)
      )
      .addMapping("call", "{\n" +
              "      \"properties\": {\n" +
              "        \"id\": {\n" +
              "          \"type\": \"string\"},\n" +
              "        \"number\": {\n" +
              "          \"type\": \"string\"},\n" +
              "        \"name\": {\n" +
              "          \"type\": \"string\"}\n" +
              "      }\n" +
              "  }")     
      .get();              

        String json = "{" +

              "\"id\":\"1\"," +
              "\"number\":\"123333333\"," +
              "\"name\":\"Sharon Tries Elastic\"" +
          "}";

    IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("calls", "call")
            .setSource(json)
            .get();

    // Index name
    String _index = response.getIndex();
    // Type name
    String _type = response.getType();
    // Document ID (generated or not)
    String _id = response.getId();
    // Version (if it's the first time you index this document, you will get: 1)
    long _version = response.getVersion();
```

}
can help please 
thank you